# Can i repo initialize multiple source code branches in one directory?

Tags: git, download, android, github

repo is a tool that manages download of android source code from github.

To download a branch (say b1) source code, we do,,

**repo init -u url -b b1**

I want to download multiple branches (gingerbread, ics, jb, kk) source code into the same directory. Is it possible?

Comment: If you do that wouldn't you have duplicate files and thus conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Once you use repo to initialize your local copy of the code for a single branch you should be able to use normal git commands to obtain the other branches.

- `git remote -v`  will list the remote branches available to you.
- `git fetch` will download the remotes
- `git checkout <name>` will checkout the branch using the short name and switch your working copy to that branch.

[git-fetch docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

[git-remote docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)

[git-checkout docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Answer (score 0):

If the URL for all branches is same, then it is possible.

Basically you need to `repo init` without the URL option on initializing subsequent branches in the same working folder.

```
repo init -u URL -b branch1
repo sync
repo init -b branch2
repo sync
repo init -b branch3
repo sync
```

This downloads all branches to the same `.repo` folder in the working directory.

[See my answer here.](https://superuser.com/a/1000590/483465)