# Download multiple branches to the same directory using repo

Tags: linux, git, python, android, repository

repo is a python script that manages cyanogenmod source code download.

to download cm-10.1 branch, repo command is,

> cd ~/cm-10.1
>
> repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-10.1
>
> cd ~/cm-11

then we can use --reference option to download cm-11 source code like

> repo init --reference=~/cm-10.1 -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-11.0

but, that downloads the delta data into cm-11 directory.

I want to download all the cyanogenmod branches in single directory and build as required. How can i do this?

Comment: The branches need to stay separate. That's why they're separated into different branches in the first place: that way files can be changed without affecting the files in other branches. Why are you trying to download them all into the same directory?

Comment: to download the 2nd branch i use --reference option which is path sensitive. And to download further branches, multiple references cannot be set which means i have to download lot more data which i might already have in different branches..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same [URL](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git) for all the branches, you can download them to a single folder, and still they are kept separate.

You can download multiple branches of project files into a single `.repo` folder in a single working directory. This saves disk space and eliminates hurdles like path sensitive `repo --reference` , inability to use multiple references.

To download all branches into same `.repo` folder, do

```
repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-10.1
repo sync
repo init -b cm-10.2
repo sync
repo init -b cm-11.0
repo sync
```

and the list goes..
This downloads all the branches to the single `.repo` folder in a single working directory. When initializing a second branch, we donot provide the `-u url` option because we are reusing a different branch from local repo.

After `repo sync` the working directory contains the last initialized branch and this is completely harmless. We are only concerned about the working directory, not the contents of `.repo` folder. The branches still stay separate.

You may occasionally use `repo forall -c git gc` to pack all loose objects into pack files.